# how to select an item in a combobox in another form when combobox is binded to a table in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, parameter-passing

I know it may be a duplicate question but previous question did not solve my problem.

I have `Form1` and `Form2`. In `Form1` there is a `dataGridView` with a field called `category`.

In `form2` I have set a `combobox`. I send data from field `category` of `dataGridView` in `form1` to this `combobox` in `Form2`.

I have made the `identifier` of this `combobox` public. There is an `update button` in `Form1`.

I want when I select a row and click on `update button`, `Form2` opens and the `combobox` that is there shows the value of field `category` of `dataGridView` of `Form1.`

This is the code:

```
Form2 fr2 = new Form2();  

fr2.cmbCategory.Text = dgvProduct.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 

fr2.Show();
```

Then in `Form2` I have set the `DataSource` of `cmbCategory` to `tblCategory`, and set it’s `Display member` to field `code`.

I want `cmbCategory` to show all items of `field code` in `tblCategory` and at the same time, one of those items be selected. And so the selected item should be the one that I pass to it from `Form1`.

I wonder how can it be done? I’m new in coding and I really appreciate if you answer in a simple way. I have used visual c# to do all this.

Comment: don;t make the combobox public. pass the category into `form2` 's constructor. `form2` can handle whatever it needs on it's own (another database query). to grab the list of whatever shares that category. then bind to the combo box. a combo cox is useless with one entry.

Comment: Would you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

**Updated: Use Text instead of SelectedItem**

In your **Form1 cs** file:

```
private void UpdateButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int category = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(dgvProduct.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out category);
    Form2 fr2 = new Form2(category);  // You are calling parameterized constructor for Form2
    fr2.Show();
}
```

Now in your **Form2 cs** file:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public int Category { get; set; }  // Property for selected category (You need this only if you need the category outside Form2 constructor)

    public Form2()  // Default constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(int category) // Contructor with string parameter
    {
        Category = category;
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbCategory.Text = Category.ToString();  **// Use Text property instead of SelectedItem.**
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. Would you explain a little bit about `ComboBox Binding logic`. I want to bind `ComboBox` to table `tbl_category` and set `SelectedValue` to field `code` of this table. I had done it with `property` pane but I could not write the code for that. I don't know if that is enough or not.

Comment: @hamed please share your code the way you have done, edit your question and add code.

Comment: Well I wrote the code exactly as you said. Then in `Form2` I chose `cmbCategory` and from `properties pane`, set its `DataSource` to `tblCategoryBindingSource` and from `DataBinding` part set `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` and `Text` to field `code` of `tbl_category`. I did not write any code for that.

Comment: so that's looks fine, what is not working? is there any error

Comment: The problem is that if I do not bind `ComboBox` to a `table` the `ComboBox` in `Form2` shows the exact value that is selected in `Form1`.

But when I bind it to a `table's data`, it does not select the item that is chosen in `Form1` among items that are bind to it and it just select the first item.

Comment: Still the same answer.

Comment: @hamed Ok tell me exactly what do you set and to what field..  I mean you set Datasource to tblCategoryBindingSource and then what all do you set SelectedItem, SelectedValue, Text and to what do you set them? Also what is the datatype of field code of tbl_category?

Comment: Dear tariq, as mentioned before in Properties pane, from `DataBinding` part  I   set `SelectedItem` to field code of `tbl_category` and `SelectedValue` to field code of `tbl_category` and `Text` property to field code of `tbl_category` and datatype of field code of `tbl_category` is int.

Comment: @hamed , does it work now, notice i have changed datatypes. For me it's working fine !!

Comment: Well again no. I build forms again and started everything from beginning but still it does not work. It works fine till the time that I have not Set `DataSource` for `ComboBox`. Just form that moment it shows all of items of table that is bind to it but does not select any item from them. And yes I did change `datatypes`.

Comment: Thank you tariq. I think there is something wrong with properties pane. Today I could write the code for that instead of using properties pane and it works fine!!